# How to properly import RxJS by patching?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5, angular2-observables

I have an Angular project and I need to use Observables from RxJS with a few selection of operators.

This is what the documentation says:

> To import only what you need by patching (this is useful for size-sensitive bundling):
>
> ```
> import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
> import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
> import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
>
> Observable.of(1,2,3).map(x => x + '!!!'); // etc
> ```

And this is what I'm doing in my app component:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  private testObservable: Observable<string> = Observable.of(1,2,3).map(x => x + '!!!');

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.testObservable.subscribe((str: string) => {

      console.log(str);

    });

  }

}
```

This is where I get confused. When I delete the second and third import (`of` and `map`), the Observable's operators still work!

I was under the impression that using the `import 'rxjs/add/operator/*';` would only add the operators I need and skip importing the rest of them. However, I can see that all the operators (static and instance) are members of the Observable class and get imported through the first import statement.

My questions are:

1. How can I properly import only the parts I need and exclude the rest?
2. What's the point of using `import 'rxjs/add/operator/*';` if all operators are already a member of the Observable class?

Comment: You may want to update to RxJS 5.5. This release makes imports of operators more comfortable introducing lettable operators: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the lettable operators. I am using RxJS 5.5 but I wasn't aware of the new feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're importing map somewhere else, too, not just in your component. Try not importing something exotic, say, bufferToggle. It will throw error. Map is imported and patched all over, perhaps even from Angular itself.

So, importing specific operators still makes sense. import * would suck, but import just map reduces your bundle size.

Comment: So if the map operator is already imported by Angular, do I need to import it individually? Or can I just import Observable in my component and use the already-imported map operator on it without importing it directly inside the component?

Comment: Well that's not good practice. See, map is common, so it's likely it is imported somewhere. But if it isn't, or even if it is, your function might call .map() before it was defined and global Observable patched, you'd get an error. And this loading depends on how, say, webpack would sort out your modules. Say you import a flatMap operator, but in a lazy module. And you use it, without import, in your main module. Your main component will break. A pattern I've picked up is to have global "operators.ts" file where I import all the operators, then import this "operators.ts" in my main app module.

Comment: Got it! The `operators.ts` thing is really useful, thanks for sharing.